# Java: Highscore method

Tags: java, variables

I have a program and want to create a simple highscore method for it. The method will only tell if the current amount of points is higher than the ones before.

```
public class Highscore {    
public static int Highscore(int poang) {

    int count = 0;
    int poäng1 = 0;
    int poäng2 = 0;
```

As you see in above, the counter is set to `0;`. This is to save the first entry. However, it resets to 0 every time the method is being used. How can i recode this? Here is the rest of the code:

```
    if (count == 0) {
        poäng1 = poang;
        count++;
    } else if (count > 0) {         
            if (poäng2 > poäng1) {              
                poäng1 = poäng2;
            }
    }
    return poäng1; 

    }   
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give some examples of what the expected input and output is from this method

Comment: Why are you surprised it's reset to 0 every time the method is called, since the very first instruction in the method is `int count = 0;`? You probably want that variable to be a field, rather than a local variable. Also, for your own good, don't name a method the same way as the class it belongs to, and respect the Java naming conventions: methods start with a lowercase letter. You shoud also avoid letters like ä in the code. Stick to ASCII.

Comment: it will reset to 0...
write int count = 0; out of Highscore(int poang).

Comment: @JBNizet I am not confused, I am telling you that, that is my problem. I am aware of the conventions, but this is just for my personal use.

Comment: @ShaileshYadav In that case, I cannot use the `count` inside my method.

Comment: And what prevents you from respecting these conventions even if it's for your personal use? Why not get into the habit of producing good code, instead of getting into the habit of producing bad code? Regarding your problem, as I said, the variable should be a field, not a local variable.

Comment: who told you you cannot use the count inside my method. just declare static int count = 0; outside Highscore(int poang){}

Comment: BTW, the code is not for your own use, since you're asking us questions about it, and thus ask us to read and understand it.

Comment: @JBNizet For god's sake.. give me a break, it is 10 lines of code. If you are just here to complain, please go. You have already disliked my question.

Comment: If you can't accept advices, then *you* should go. Remember: you're the one having problems, you're the ones asking for help, and we're the ones helping you, for free, with **good** advices that will help **you** in the long run. I'm not complaining. I'm telling you what to do: use a field. And I'm telling you how to not be confused by your own code and make your question easier to read and answer: respect the naming conventions, use characters and words that everybody on an English web site is able to read and type.

Comment: by the way ainvox, JB Nizet is right... you should follow proper naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are redefined (and re-initialized) every time the block (in your case - a static method) is entered. If you want them to keep their value beyond the scope of that block, they should be defined outside of it.

In this case, you could have `count` as a (static) member:

```
private static int count = 0;
public static int Highscore(int poang) {
    // Code comes here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After the first entry I get the end result to `0`. Why?

Comment: @Ainvox please post a new question with the details of how you're calling the method and what params you're passing.